# How to load a dll into VS c++, which acts like a wrapper to another CAPL code?

Tags: dll, wrapper, dllexport, capl

I am trying to reference functions in a 3rd party dll file through CAPL Script. Since, I cannot directly call them, I am trying to create a wrapper which exports the functions in the dll.

`int MA_Init(char *TbName, int Option);` is the function in the dll file.

The wrapper code for this is

```
int CAPLEXPORT far CAPLPASCAL CMA_Init(char *TbName, int Option)
{
return MA_Init(*TbName, Option);
}
```

I am trying to use

`HINSTANCE DllHandel = loadlibrary("C:\\Turbo.dll");` to load the library and

`typedef int(*TESTFnptr)(char, int);
TESTFnptr fn= (TESTFnptr)getprocaddress(DllHandle, "MA_Init");` to resolve the function address.

However the compiler says the function `"MA_Init()"` is not defined. I am not sure if I am using the correct procedure to load the dll into my visual C++ project. Has anyone tried doing this or knows how it's done? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard procedure would be to include the corresponding `.lib` file to VS project. Go to "Project - Properties - Configuration Properties - Linker - Additional Dependencies" and add `turbo.lib` on a new line. Then you'll need to include the corresponding `turbo.h` header file which contains the definition for `MA_Init` function.

In this case, you'll be able to call `MA_Init` directly, as you do now. The compiler will happily find the definition of `MA_Init` in the header file, and the linker will find the reference to `MA_Init` in the `.lib` file.

If you don't have `turbo.h` file, you can create one yourself provided you know the prototypes of all functions you want to use. Just put definitions like

```
int MA_Init(char *TbName, int Option);
```

there and include it.

If you don't have `turbo.lib` file, you'll have to proceed with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. Obviously, you cannot call `MA_Init` by name in this case, since it is undefined. You'll have to call the pointer returned by `GetProcAddress` instead:

```
TESTFnptr fn = (TESTFnptr)GetProcAddress(DllHandle, "MA_Init");
int CAPLEXPORT far CAPLPASCAL CMA_Init(char *TbName, int Option)
{
    return fn(TbName, Option);
}
```

PS. Notice I removed the start in front of `TbName`?

PPS. Don't forget to include your wrapper function, `CMA_Init`, to `CAPL_DLL_INFO_LIST`, otherwise it will not be accessible in CANoe/CANalyzer.